# How do I signal to a user to replace text in a filepath?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft

Say I want to tell a user where a file is on a shared drive. For this example, the file is at `"O:\my_name\Main Directory\file.xlsx"`. How do I tell a user to replace my name with their name? Is  `"O:\<USERNAME>\Main Directory\file.xlsx"` a viable option?

Comment: `"O:\<your_user_name>\Main Directory\file.xlsx"`?

Comment: Yes. Fixed .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [davidpostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) commented, using `"O:\<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE\Main Directory\file.xlsx"` should be enough for most relatively tech-savvy users to understand and access the Excel file.

But, in the event that isn't enough, you could also connect to the machine in the background without needing to RDP, use SCCM Remote Control, or GoToAssist (or similar solution) via File Explorer using `\\HOSTNAME\C$\Users\USERNAME\Desktop` and [create a shortcut to the file there](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-create-desktop-shortcut-windows-4584822) for the user in the background.

Alternatively, you could connect to the O: drive mentioned in the path and, If you’re using W10, hold down Shift on your keyboard and right-click on the file, folder, or library for which you want a link. Then, select “Copy as path” in the contextual menu and paste the link into an email, messaging App (e.g. Teams, Slack, etc.) or document you need to use to share that info with said user.

Comment: I definitely have tech-savy users. It was more a question of convention and what is the standard for sharing filepaths.

Comment: It's really up to you, depending on the user base and how much "handholding" is needed to address the request. As long as it makes sense to the human on the other end or is a process that you can do remotely as an admin.

Answer (score 1):

If the `<USERNAME>` actually the same as their Windows username in 100% of cases then `O:\%USERNAME%\Main Directory\file.xlsx` might work without them needing to manually change anything.

%USERNAME% is an environment variable in Windows that resolves to the current username. It will work in command (`cmd`) windows as well as Explorer.

Comment: So are you saying the standard is to use a `"%___%"` rather than a `"<___>"`?

Comment: @Jsleshem `%USERNAME%` is an environment variable in Windows that resolves to the current username.